# How can i handle Button click which is located in another button in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I just made Button which has HBox inside the button.
And when i click inside button, the outer button is clicked too.
I just want to make one button can be clicked at once.
How can i handle this Buttons?

This is JavaFX controller code.

```
Button b = new Button();
Button front = new Button("Stop");
front.setPrefWidth(50);
front.setOnAction((e) -> {
    System.out.println("front click");
});
HBox h = new HBox();
h.getChildren().addAll(front);
b.setGraphic(h);

b.setOnAction((e) -> {
        System.out.println("back click");
});
```

and when i run this code and when i click front button the result is

```
front click
back click
front click
back click
front click
back click
front click
back click
front click
back click
front click
back click
```

when i click front button, back button is clicked, too.
how can i handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Event Consume`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html#consume--) should work.

```
front.setOnAction((e) -> {
    System.out.println("front click");
    e.consume();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i want :)